# PHP Client to Node js Server. Connection never "ends"

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, curl, tcp

I have a simple webpage that is supposed to submit a "csv" like string to a server. For this I require an API to receive the data string and save the string as a text file.

The page is using PHP and the Server is Node js

Code examples:

PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$path = '/test.txt';
$url = "http://none.of.your.business.com:8280/";

$data = array('filePath' => $path,
      'message' => $csv);
$data_string = json_encode($string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Node Server:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '0.0.0.0';
var PORT = 8280;


net.createServer(function(sock) {

                var body = "";

                console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

                sock.on('data', function (data) {
                                body += data;
                                console.log("Partial body: " + body);
                                });

                sock.on('end', function () {

                                console.log("ENDED");
                                console.log("Body: " + body);
                                });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

With this code (and other alternatives) the "end" event is never called and the connection never closed. Resulting in a 300 second timeout on the PHP script. I reckon its something fairly simple, am I supposed to send something back to the PHP to say "done"?, but I'm inexperienced with TCP connections. I get the  following "console.log'ged" on the server:

```
[root@xxxxxxxxx fileWriter]# node index.js
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:8280
CONNECTED: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:52766
Partial body: POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.com:8280
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 440

{"filePath":"/test.txt","message":"\"WORKFLOWID\",\"PARENTWORKFLOWID\",\"SOURCEINSTANCEID\",\"WORKFLOWTYPECODE\",\"DATECREATED\",\"DATEUPDATED\",\"ASSETID\",\"PVN\",\"IVN\",\"PROVIDERID\",\"TITLE\",\"SERIESTITLE\",\"OFFERDATE\",\"LASTOFFERDATE\",\"REGION\",\"RELEASEPHASE\",\"WORKFLOWSTATUSID\",\"DURATIONMILLIS\"\\n\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"04-Dec-17 14.55.05.000000 PM\",\"TITL0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"-1\",\"\"\n"}
```

Comment: try ading `Connection: Close` to your headers

Answer (score 0):

Following code on the server side (Node.js) has solved my issues. Seems sending a response closed the connection.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
http.createServer((request, response) => {
                const { headers, method, url } = request;
                let body = [];
                request.on('error', (err) => {
                                console.error(err);
                                }).on('data', (chunk) => {
                                        body.push(chunk);
                                        }).on('end', () => {
                                                body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

                                                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                                                response.on('error', (err) => {
                                                                console.error(err);
                                                                });

                                                response.statusCode = 200;
                                                response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                                                const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };
                                                fs.appendFileSync(json.filePath,json.message);
                                                response.write("Succesfully written " + json.filePath);
                                        //      response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
                                                response.end();

                                });
}).listen(8280);
```